# Butterfly/Moth identification: Puppa is half green, half brown, and 1,5cm long, found in Upper Austria

Tags: species-identification, zoology

**Question: What butterfly is going to evolve out of the puppa illustrated in the attached picture?**

**Characteristics:** Puppa is half green, half brown, and 1,5cm long 
**Further details:** I don't know if this is relevant we found it on our mint plant, presumably it has eaten its leaves along with the lice on it.
[image: A butterfly or moth puppa found in Upper Austria]
[image: A butterfly or moth puppa found in Upper Austria]

Comment: Did you pull it out of the silk in the photo to take the picture?  If so, it is probably a moth species. You will probably need to wait for it to emerge to identify it.

Comment: @user22542 No i did not pull it out of the silk, no person did. However we had severe rain once in a while in the last 1 and a half weeks and I was not present at the spot where the plant stands, hence I cannot tell if it had an impact